# How can I use a helm template function defined in _helpers.tpl, in another function in _helpers.tpl in Helm charts?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have the following functions defined in my `templates/_helpers.tpl` file

```
{{/*
Function to get min CPU units
*/}}
{{- define "microserviceChart.minCpuUnits" -}}
{{- printf "%dm" index .Values.valuesPerEnvironment.cpuUnits ((pluck .Values.environment .Values.environments | first | default .Values.environments.sandbox) | int) | quote }}
{{- end }}

{{/*
Function to get max CPU units
*/}}
{{- define "microserviceChart.maxCpuUnits" -}}
{{ index .Values.valuesPerEnvironment.maxCpuUnits ((pluck .Values.environment .Values.environments | first | default .Values.environments.sandbox) | int) | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

But I want to do this

```
{{/*
Function to get index value
*/}}
{{- define "microserviceChart.Index" -}}
{{ pluck .Values.environment .Values.environments | first | default .Values.environments.sandbox) | int }}
{{- end }}

{{/*
Function to get min CPU units
*/}}
{{- define "microserviceChart.minCpuUnits" -}}
{{- printf "%dm" index .Values.valuesPerEnvironment.cpuUnits (use_above_function) | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

Can I do it? If so how? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need [the `include` function](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#the-include-function)?  (Note that it always returns a string.)  Or, could you use a separate `helm install -f prod-values.yaml` file per environment, with a simpler YAML layout?

Comment: I tried the include, and use it in my other `templates/*.yaml` files. I just can't make it work within the `_helpers.tpl` file itself. I want to shy away from having multiple YAML files based on environment. That's the whole point behind templates.